# How to send data from JavaScript file to views.py django?

Tags: python, django

How can I send data ( the user_to_follow in this example ) to my views.py function ( follow ) to do some updates?

I'm trying to send the username from my JavaScript and then add the logged-in username to that username following list ( all done in my views.py function )

Views.py.

```
def follow(request, profile_to_follow):
    try:
        user_to_follow = User.objects.get(username=profile_to_follow)
        user_to_following = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({"error": "Profile not found."}, status=404)
    if request.method == "PUT":
        user_to_following.following.add(user_to_follow)
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

index.js

```
function follow_user(user_to_follow){
    // How To send the user_to_follow to my views.py method.
    // to add the current logged in user to the user_to_follow following list
    console.log(user_to_follow)
}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),

    # API Routes
    path("posts", views.compose_post, name="compose_post"),
    path("posts/all_posts", views.show_posts, name="show_posts"),
    path("posts/<int:post_id>", views.post, name="post"),
    path("profile/<str:profile>", views.display_profile, name="profile"),
    path("<str:profile_posts>/posts", views.display_profile_posts, name="profile_posts"),
    path("follow/<str:user_to_follow>", views.follow, name="follow"),
]
```

Comment: If you found my answer as useful and correct can you mark it as accepted?

Comment: Yes sir, thanks! I haven't yet because I am still learning it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method would be using an Ajax Query to send data from templates to your views.py

*index.js*

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     function follow_user(user_to_follow){
     $.ajax({
         type: "PUT",
         url: "{% url 'follow' user_to_follow %}",
         data: {
                user_data: user_to_follow,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
         success: function( data )
         {
         alert("Successful Added User to list");
         }
     });
     });
 });
</script>
```

*views.py*

```
def follow(request, profile_to_follow):
    try:
        user_to_follow = User.objects.get(username=profile_to_follow)
        user_to_following = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({"error": "Profile not found."}, status=404)
    if request.method == "PUT" and request.is_ajax():
        user_to_following.following.add(user_to_follow)
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

> request.is_ajax()

This will return a boolean value based on whether the request is an AJAX call or not.

You can also refer to this documentation https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#options